# Disprove the statement: If $g\circ f=I_X$then $f\circ g=I_Y$.

Tags: functions, examples-counterexamples, inverse-function

If someone could walk me through this I would greatly appreciate it.

> Disprove the following statement:
>
> Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$  and $g : Y \rightarrow X$ be functions. If $g\circ f=I_X$then $f\circ g=I_Y$

Comment: What sort of examples have you tried so far? That's the general strategy: Try things. If they don't work, try more things, stopping to think about why your counterexample-hopefuls didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first counterexample one tries should be the simplest. Let
$$X=\{\#\}, \ \ Y = \{*,\&\}.$$
Define
$$f(\#) = * \ \mbox{ and } \ g(*) = g(\&) = \#  $$
Note that
$$ (g\circ f)(\#) = \#$$
Now examine $(f\circ g)$. Do you see the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be the natural inclusion of the real line into the plane, and let $g$ be the natural projection of the plane onto the real line.

Answer (score 0):

Let the domain of $f$ be the integers and the domain of $g$ be the reals.  Then take

$$f(n) = n \\ g(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor$$

It is easy for see that for all  $n$ in the domain of $f$, 
$$g(f(n)) = \lfloor n \rfloor = n$$
so $g\circ f = I_X$. Yet for real $x$ (in the domain of $g$)
$$
f(g(x)) = \lfloor x \rfloor \neq x
$$
unless $x$ happens to be a integer.  So $f\circ g \neq I_Y$

Now try the same problem but specifying that $X$ and $Y$ be the same space.  You can still find a counterexample.  (Hint - the drange of $X$ need not be all of $Y$).

Answer (score -1):

Let $X=\{0\}$ and $Y=\mathbb{Z}$. Now define $f:X\to Y$ by $f(0)=0$ and $g:Y\to X$ by $g(x)=0$.

Now $g\circ f= I_X$ and $f\circ g\neq I_Y$ since $f\circ g(1)=f(0)=0\neq I_Y(1)$.

Comment: The answer is correct, so (+1) to neutralise the downvote.